# ¿Como puedo cambiar dinamicamente el look & feel de un Jbutton de java?

Tags: java, java-swing

Quiero que la GUI tenga el L&F del sistema operativo por defecto, sin embargo hay un caso especifico con unos Jbutton donde necesito removerles el L&F porque quiero que estos sean planos y no tengan la apariencia de Windows ya que esto arruina mi GUI, ¿exite la forma de cambiar dinamicamente el L&F o ponerle a los Jbutton la apariencia por defecto?

Answer (score 0):

He visto algunos métodos que iteran los LNF del sistema y escogen uno; y hasta tiran excepciones y hacen logs. Para mí es más práctico escoger un LNF que pueda mostrar todos los componentes que requiero. Quizás luego perfeccione eso, pero de momento este LNF resuleve mis necesidades y solo ocupa una línea y solo requiero asegurarme de incluir esa clase en el JAR a usar:

```
   System.setProperty("swing.defaultlaf","javax.swing.plaf.nimbus.NimbusLookAndFeel");
```

Comment: Lo he probado pero eso me cambia la apariencia de todo y me tocaría reiniciar el diseño de la GUI... igualemnte muchas gracias